# WAMP conflicting with SQL Server port can't virtual host

Tags: sql-server, wordpress, apache, wamp, wampserver

I had WAMP running fine using a virtual hosts so that I could do my local wordpress development on my PC

I needed SQL-Server-express for something unrelated so I installed that and WAMP failed to run (only 1 of 2 services worked)

I changed the Apache port defaults from 80 to 8080 and the MySQL from 3306 to 3307.

I reset, and WAMP seemed fine (2 of 2 services worked)

I can access http://localhost:8080 and see the WAMP page, but I can't use any virtual hosts I have setup

I went to `httpd-vhosts.conf` and this is contents of file. The latter part is what I have for my local wordpress dev site

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
    <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
#


<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName woo1lynda.dev
    DocumentRoot "c:/www/woo1lynda"
    <Directory  "c:/www/woo1lynda/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

why won't my virtual host `woo1lynda.dev` work after I changed ports?

The error I get is

> HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found.

Comment: If you change the port Apache is listening on you also have to use it on ALL your urls So for example `woo1lynda.dev:8080` should work

Comment: It would have been better to work out which port was now being used and only change the ONE port with a problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried using woo1lynda.dev:8080 but it didn't work, but I 
 realized afterward it was port 3306 being used. I ended up just disabling SQL-Server reporting services which used that port

Answer (score 1):

I just disabled SQL-Server reporting services which uses port 3306 that conflicts with WAMP

Under SQL-Server configuration manager → SQL Service Services

[image]

Also, **services.msc** → SQL Server reporting Services → Manual startup

so it doesn't have to run everytime I boot up PC